# Communicate through command line with active process

Tags: node.js

Very simple `Node.js` application. Application on start reads a file called `config.js`.

app.js

```
const config = require("./config");

const doStuff = (req, res, next) => {
    // using config.b or config.a or config.c
};

router.post("/", doStuff);

module.exports = router;
```

config.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
    a: 5,
    b: 10,
    c: 11
};
```

Lets say i am starting my application with `PM2`

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Is it possible to communicate with app.js process from command line (terminal) and make it so it reloads `config.js` file. It's possible for example for `nginx` or `php`. Is it possible for `Node.js` process?

The important is so its done through command line and doesnt interupt the process flow or cause downtime.

Comment: What do you want to communicate? Also, which operating system? It would be easy to send signals and define signal handlers, but that will only give you some bits, not a lot of bandwidth. Obviously you would also open sockets in your application or start an http server and then send curl requests or similar. Or you could keep reading from a fiel. So the easiest option really depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: i need to avoid http or socket transmission, otherwise it would be very easy with listener invoked externally. I need something like command typed to terminal that will cause this config.js file reload. Is that possible?

Comment: again, what's the breadth of what you want to communicate. Is it just a bit (reload), or do you need various commands. If just the former, then signals are probably a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only need to trigger a reload of the config, then you can use signals:

```
const config = require("./config");

const doStuff = (req, res, next) => {
    // using config.b or config.a or config.c
};

router.post("/", doStuff);

module.exports = router;

process.on('SIGUSR1', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGUSR1. Reloading config.');
  reloadConfig();
});
```

And then:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 PID
```

where `PID` is the process id of your running node process.

Comment: this is actually exactly what i was looking for, very simple and does the job, thank you